Fourier series coinciding with a meromorphic function on the real line
Suppose $f$ is a meromorphic function on $\mathbb{C}$ such that
$$f(x)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty b_n \sin nx,\quad \forall x\in\mathbb{R}.$$
The function $f$ has poles away from the real axis.
Question
Then is it automatically true that
$$f(z)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty b_n \sin nz$$
where $z$ is any point of a certain infinite strip of non-zero breadth containing the real axis?
Thoughts
I haven't been able to find any counterexample. Intuitively, I think it is true. Because when we rewrite the Fourier series in terms of exponentials and let $\zeta=e^{iz}$, it gets transformed to a Laurent series in $\zeta$ and since Laurent series converge "annulus-wise", the Fourier series should converge "strip-wise" and be analytic in the strip.
But experience has taught me that using intuition for Fourier series is bad: hence this question. I know that some Fourier series coincide with analytic functions only on proper subsets of the real axis, but everytime I saw it happen, it was because of some obstacle like non-existence of the real derivative of the Fourier series.

First note that since $f(x+2\pi)=f(x)$ on the real axis we get that  $f(z+2\pi)=f(z)$ for all $z \in \mathbb C$.
By compacity, in the rectangle $0 \le \Re z \le 2\pi, -1 \le \Im z \le 1$ we can have only finitely many poles of $f$, and by periodicity it follows that if $z_0$ is a pole of $f$ we have $|\Im z_0| \ge c>0$ for a fixed $c>0$.
Now for every $w \ne 0$ let's define $g(w)=f(z_w)$ where $e^{iz_w}=w$. This doesn't depend on the choice of $z_w$ since any two such differ by some $2\pi k$ for an integer $k$ and $f$ is periodic with period $2\pi$. Since we can fix a continuous (hence analytic determination) of $z_w$ in a small neighborhood of any $w \ne 0$ it follows that $g$ is meromorphic on the punctured plane and its poles have a positive distance from the unit circle as their modulus is either at most $e^{-c}$ or at least $e^c$.
In particular, $g$ is analytic in the annulus $e^{-c} < |w| < e^{c}$ so has a Laurent series $g(w)=\sum_{n \in \mathbb Z} c_n w^n$ there converging uniformly on compact subsets (so for example on $e^{-c/2} \le |w| \le e^{c/2}$). In particular, $c_n$ are the Fourier coefficients of $g$ restricted to the unit circle.
But writing $$f(x)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty b_n \sin nx=\sum_{n \in \mathbb Z} a_n e^{inx},,\quad \forall x\in\mathbb{R}$$ it follows by defintion that $g(w)=\sum_{n \in \mathbb Z} a_n w^n, w=e^{ix}$.
Now there is a fairly deep theorem that says that if $g$ is integrable on the unit circle (eg continuous like here) any representation by a trigonometric series that converges everywhere to $g$, then that must be the Fourier series of $g$ so $a_n=c_n$ and going back to $f$ we indeed get that $f(z)=\sum b_n \sin nz$ for $|\Im z| \le c/2$ uniformly.
Note that if we know apriori that $\sum b_n \sin nx$ is the Fourier series of $f$ (as a periodic function on the real axis) or that the convergence is "nice" (which implies that $\sum b_n \sin nx$ is the Fourier series) we do not need to appeal to the deep theorem above as the result follows by the unicity of the Fourier coefficients.
